# Datatables : How to Set 'targets' Dynamically in columnDefs

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm having datatable and dropdown. Dropdown having a list of columns. I want to exclude the selected column from search. I want to set 'targets' dynamically in columnDefs when User changes dropdown

This is my code:

```
var columns = [];
//When I hardcode like this: var columns = [0, 1, 2] it works fine

$(document).ready(function () {
    getData();
    columns.push(eval($('#dropdown').val()));
    $('#dropdown').change(function () {
        columns = [];
        columns.push(eval($('#dropdown').val()));
    })
});

function getData() {
    $('#MyTable').DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        ajax: ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "API/Users.asmx/getData",
            dataType: "json",
            dataSrc: function (data) {
                buildMyDatatable(data)
            }
        }),
        columnDefs: [
            { "searchable": false, "targets": columns } //I want this to be dynamic
        ]
    });
}
```